# remove rasters with 'NA' values after batch reclassify in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply, raster

I used to for loop to iterate thru a bunch of rasters (n=533) and `reclassify` them based on converting certain values (less than 353.3) to 'NA'. I would now like to have an efficient way to search thru the list of reclassified rasters and remove rasters that have all 'NA' values (see output examples below). How can this be done?

```
wfrastlist <- list.files(path = "/path/to/rasters/", 
pattern='*.TIF$', all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)

#generate a reclassification matrix 
#in this example, values less than 353.2 are assigned a new value of 
#'NA' 
m <- c(-Inf, 353.2, NA)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

#function to reclassify rasters and write a new reclassified .tif 
#file for each

batch_reclass <- function(wfrastlist){
  for (i in 1:length(wfrastlist)) {
    #read in raster
    r <-raster(paste0("/path/to/rasters/", wfrastlist[i]))
    #perform the reclassifcation
    rc <- reclassify(r, rclmat)
    #write each reclass to a new file 
    writeRaster(rc, filename = 
    paste0("/path/to/reclassified/rasters/", "rc_", wfrastlist[i]), 
    format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
  }
}
#run the function
batch_reclass(wfrastlist)

#example output
#raster with values within new range
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 412, 362, 149144  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 20.15372, 20.15372  (x, y)
extent      : 1531426, 1538721, 592978.7, 601282.1  (xmin, xmax, 
ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=58.5 +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-126 
+x_0=1000000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m 
+no_defs 
data source : /path/to/reclassified/rasters/rc_wfrast_basin102.tif 
names       : rc_wfrast_basin102 
values      : 412.6, 424.6  (min, max)

#raster without values within new range (i.e., missing 'values' row)
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 158, 66, 10428  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 20.15372, 20.15372  (x, y)
extent      : 1551478, 1552809, 602914.5, 606098.8  (xmin, xmax, 
ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=58.5 +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-126 
+x_0=1000000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m 
+no_defs 
data source : /path/to/reclassified/rasters/rc_wfrast_basin103.tif 
names       : rc_wfrast_basin103
```

Comment: I would do this between the reclassification and writing your raster and not after the fact. You can simply vectorize the raster and test the length of NA values eg., length(x[is.na[x]]) == length(x[])  Your test condition could also be a proportion of cells rather than all NA's. You can calculate the number of "expected" non-NA cells from the original raster.

Comment: OK, so specifically for the code above, include that line within the for loop after '#...reclassification' but before '#write...' like this?: length(rc[is.na[rc]]) == length(rc[])

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the min (or max) value of the raster is `NA`, which means that there are only NAs

```
rc <- reclassify(r, rclmat)
if (!is.na(minValue(rc))) {
    writeRaster(rc,  paste0("/path/to/reclassified/rasters/", "rc_", wfrastlist[i]), format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it really cuts to the chase and keeps it memory safe.